# Azure DevOps 2020 on-premises Renaming a Wiki

Tags: azure, wiki

we have the Azure DevOps Server 2020 on-premises. We have a couple a Wiki pages in a project but not many, about 10, with totally about 1000 lines of text.
When I try to rename a Wiki page, it tells "Loading broken wiki page links" which never ends. So it is not possible to rename a Wiki page actually.
On the dialog there is a checkbox for "Update affected links..." which is checked but also greyed out, so that it cannot be disabled.
Anybody knows how to cure that?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Same issue in Azure DevOps Server 2022.

Comment: To be more precise: when renaming or moving a page, the "Move page dialog" opens as [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/wiki/add-edit-wiki?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#reorder-a-wiki-page), but the process of "Loading broken wiki page links" never ends.
Steps to reproduce: start a new project, add a brand new wiki, create first page (title only), save page, rename page -> the dialog keeps loading forever.

Comment: Follow reported [issue](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/ADS-2020---Cannot-rename-page-in-provisi/10238186?q=wiki+move+page+dialog)

Answer (score 0):

Solved this issue by uninstalling the Wiki Search extension, as mentioned in the [issue report](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/ADS-2020---Cannot-rename-page-in-provisi/10238186#T-N10249080).

Note: I wanted to include a link to the extension in the Marketplace, but I cannot find it there. I can only include a screenshot of the page that was shown by our server before I uninstalled it. Strange, as it's developed by Microsoft and last update was recent (see screenshot).

[image: Screenshot of Wiki Search page]

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into this today, I was able to fix this by initiating a rebuild of the index for wikis at the collection level using the code-search tools Microsoft provides for managing the index. As soon as that fired off the "move" option turned blue when dragging and dropping the wiki pages even during the rebuild process. Seems like if the index is broken it can't do the operation in the background to move the pages.